# Do all members of a Facebook Group get notifications of ALL posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-notifications

If a Facebook Group has, say, 1000 members, do they *all* get notifications of *all* posts to that group? (Assuming they have simply joined/favorited, not selected anything special, like "see all".)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. By default a group member get notifications for all the post. A group member can change this setting anytime.

[How do I edit my notification settings for a group?](https://www.facebook.com/help/187225274663021?helpref=faq_content)